# Laravel - Cannot using route file name as route path name

Tags: laravel, routes

Before upgrade to latest version (8.x), I used to be able to use route file name as a part of the route URL. For example let say I have a file `routes/admin.php` containing

```
Route::get('signin', function(){
    return view('limitless.render', $data);
});
```

then I can simply go to `example.com/admin/signin` without getting a 404 error.

For certain reason I have to upgrade to latest version. But right after upgrade it, I can no longer doing that. Is it not permissible anymore of do I miss something?

Comment: Do you use route group to tell router that 'signin' should in fact be 'admin/signin'? See [Route Prefixes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-prefixes) in Laravel docs.

Comment: Like this:   ```Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('users', function () {
        // Matches The "/admin/users" URL
    });
});```

Comment: @KazikM I didn't because it's implicitly prefixed with the filename. Thank you btw maybe I should do that assuming default filename prefix no longer supported